# Can not define a Map in Intellij scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I was trying to make a Map in Intellij scala worksheet but I get this error `EmptyScope.enter`

The code I tried and failed is very simple:

```
val a = Map("a" -> 1)
```

Another error message was `Error:Error:uncaught exception during compilation: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError`

I am using version 15.0.6

Please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Map`. One or more of IntelliJ/Scala/JDK hasn't been installed properly. I suggest installing the latest version: IDEA 2016.2

Comment: Actually I had updated to the latest version before seeing this happen. When I do the same thing in scala console this does not happen.